# How to randomly call any method from a list

Tags: python, web2py-modules

Am still new to web2py and python, in my web2py app, i created this code that works well in python shell.

python modules:
The methods work in such a way that a user inputs an equation query to get an answer. If it is an addition, method1 works it out, the same to other methods being invoked to performing different codes e.g.

```
def method1():# to do additions
    name = input('Please Enter equation here: ').lower()
    if '1 + 1':
        answer = code
        return answer

def method2():# to do subtractions
    name = input('Please Enter equation here: ').lower()
    if '1 - 1':
        answer = code
        return answer
```

In the controller, I imported the methods as follows though there are many more methods than these shown

```
from applications ...... import method1
from applications ...... import method2
from applications ...... import method3
from applications ...... import method4

method1 = method1
method1 = method2
method1 = method3
method1 = method4

G0 = [method1, method2, method3, method4]

def Foo():
    code..
    for (func) in G0:
        return func()
```

The problem is that only method1 which is at position[0] in the list is invoked and not other methods. I want to randomly call any method when a user inputs any query.

Comment: do you want to randomly call a method or call all methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call methods randomly use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
def foo1():
    print "hello"

def foo2():
     print "world"

def foo3():
     print "goodbye"

def foo4():
     print "world"
GO = [foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4]

import random

def Foo():
    func = random.choice(GO)
    return func()
In [30]: Foo()
world

In [31]: Foo()
goodbye

In [32]: Foo()
hello

In [33]: Foo()
goodbye
```

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for `yield`.

```
G0 = [method1, ..., method4]

def foo():
    for method in G0:
        yield method()

method_results = foo()
type(method_results) # <class 'generator'>
for result in method_results:
    print(result)
## OUTPUT will be each result, one per line
```

Though I think the deeper problem is:

```
method1 = method1
method1 = method2 # method1 = ... huh?
method1 = method3 # help I'm trapped in an
method1 = method4 # overwrite factory....
```

Answer (score 1):

Only method1 is called because you're returning from inside the loop, so the loop exits as well. What do you want to return? A list of all return values perhaps?

```
def Foo():
    ret_list = []
    for (func) in G0:
        ret_list.append(func())
    return ret_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run all of those methods in `G0`? If so, the issue is that you're using `return func()`. The `return` keyword will exit `Foo()` as soon as it's called, which is why only one function gets called. You should just use `func()` or `result = func()` if you want to store the value.

If you only want to run one of those methods, you need to ditch the `for` loop and just use `return G0[x]()`, where `x` is the list index of the function you want to call.